# use CalendarBuilder (ical4j) from a service

Tags: android, service, thread-safety, ical4j

CalendarBuilder (from ical4j) is not thread-safe. At least it seems so. Is there any way it can be used from a service? I have a service in my android app that needs this method to run. I cannot just use an activity for the same due to some constraints. I have to use the service. Any advise will be appreciated.

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>    net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DefaultTimeZoneRegistryFactory.createRegistry(DefaultTimeZoneRegistryFactory.java:48)
>   at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder.(CalendarBuilder.java:123)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at net.fortuna.ical4j.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:77)
>   at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.TimeZoneRegistryImpl.(TimeZoneRegistryImpl.java:76)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that CalendarBuilder is not thread-safe, however I am not convinced that is the source of the problem. You can see from the source that the exception occurs when trying to load the tz.alias resource:

https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/blob/develop/src/main/java/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/TimeZoneRegistryImpl.java#L74

You may want to check that you have packaged this file with your service.

Comment: the link doesn't exist